# Getting a new CPU and motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5, intel-core2

I have the Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 2.40GHz, 8MB Cache, 1066MHz FSB, Kentsfield, Quad-Core, Socket 775, Processor and it has been nothing short of amazing since 2007. I'm now looking at the Intel Core i5-2500 3.30 GHz Quad Core Processor and was wondering if anyone could tell me how it would perform relative to my kentsfield. I realize they are generations apart and there is nothing wrong with my kentsfield..but I'm chewing RAM up like crazy and Want a 32MB motherboard.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html

Comment: I love it. You really should make this an answer so I can choose it

Comment: From **[*the* FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)**, Super User is **not** about shopping/buying recommendations.  This is what forums are for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's take a look over there...http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html